# Не работает карусель React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap, carousel

Пытаюсь создать слайдер изображений в своём реакт-приложении. Установил через npm react-bootstrap.

Прописал необходимый код, но карусель отображается не правильно, как будто в ней стили весь css убрали и остался один html. Прикрепляю скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, когда я добавляю несколько изображений через Carousel.Item, получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что в самом верху появилось три пункта навигации по слайдеру, однако он всё ещё не работает.

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import oneImg from '../assets/1.png';
import twoImg from '../assets/2.png';
import threeImg from '../assets/3.png';

export default function CarouselBox() {
  return (
    <Carousel>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src= {oneImg}
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src= {oneImg}
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src= {oneImg}
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Comment: Вот package.json строки на которых  видно что react-bootstrap есть:
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }

Comment: ну так может стили и не подключились, где видно что Вы их используете? что-то типа `import 'styles.css'`

Comment: @DaniilLoban, так он разве не прописываются по умолчанию для карусели? Никогда не видел, чтобы их создавали с нуля

Comment: не создавать с нуля, а подключить те что идут либой, она не может идти без `css`

Comment: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` вот [это](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css) кто будет за Вас подключать?

Comment: @DaniilLoban, действительно, заработало. Спасибо вам!

Comment: пожалуйста, и этот вопрос от невнимательности, поэтому его можно удалить, вряд ли он несет какую-то пользу, я даже не вижу смысла писать на него ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:
Необходимо дописать ещё одну строчку импорта для подключения стилей

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Спасибо, Daniil Loban